# How can I add custom label to overpass turbo result

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

For example given this overpass turbo query: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/ctg

How could I change all of the names shown over those areas to say "foo" instead?

What I have tried that does not work:

- Change the `text:name` to `text:foo`
- Use the `set tag=value` syntax like this:

  `{{style:
  node,way,relation {
  set bar=foo;
  text:bar;
  }
  }}`
- Add `"` or `'` around the tag and text values

Comment: Added follow up: https://github.com/tyrasd/overpass-turbo/issues/235

Answer (score 2):

At this moment it is not possible - see https://github.com/tyrasd/overpass-turbo/issues/235

This enhancement is proposed, currently issue is not rejected, there was some development activity in 2017.

As usual with open source making pull request may be helpful if someone really wants this feature.